# nodejs test - TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: node.js, testing, amazon-s3, sinon

For my following code, `S3Handler`, I have the following test, which is returning the error: `TypeError: undefined is not a function`.

The line throwing the error is where `testedModule._get(bucketName, imgName, function () {`

Why am I getting this error?

`S3Handler`:

```
'use strict';

var s3 = new (require('aws-sdk')).S3();

var S3Handler = {};

S3Handler._get = function (bucketName, imgName, callback) {

    var params = {
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Key: imgName
    };

    s3.getObject(params, function (error, data) {
        if (error) {
            return callback(error, null);
        }
        console.log(data);
        return callback(null, data);
    });
};
```

test:

```
describe("S3Handler", function () {
    describe("S3Handler._get", function () {
        var testedModule, imgName, callbackSpy, bucketName, getStub, fakeResponse, s3Stub;

        before(function () {

            fakeResponse = {Body: "Image content"};

            imgName = "test.jpg";

            bucketName = "testBucket";

            callbackSpy = sinon.spy();

            getStub = sinon.stub();

            s3Stub = sinon.stub().returns({getObject: getStub});


            testedModule = proxyquire("../S3Handler.js", {
                'aws-sdk': {
                    "S3": s3Stub
                }
            });
        });

        it("fetch object from S3Bucket", function () {
            getStub.withArgs(bucketName, imgName).callsArgWith(1, null, fakeResponse);
            testedModule._get(bucketName, imgName, function () {
                callbackSpy.apply(null, fakeResponse);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: `testedModule._get(bucketName, imgName, function () {`

Answer (score 0):

So of course, paying more attention when tired does help.

It would also help if I had exported my module!!

```
'use strict';

var s3 = new (require('aws-sdk')).S3();

var S3Handler = {};

S3Handler._get = function (bucketName, imgName, callback) {

    var params = {
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Key: imgName
    };

    s3.getObject(params, function (error, data) {
        if (error) {
            return callback(error, null);
        }
        console.log(data);
        return callback(null, data);
    });
};

module.exports = S3Hanlder;
```